# How to encode special characters in e-mail-adresses

Tags: perl, email, encoding, special-characters

E-Mail-Adresses do not only consist of this parts:

> localpart@domain.tld

The complete string in the next line (including the part between the quotation marks, the quotation marks itself and the angle brackets) is also a valid address:

> "John Doe" <localpart@domain.tld>

And when I replace "John Doe" with my own name, I get an address, that I can enter in my E-Mail-Client without getting any complaints (Note the »**ö**« in my last name which is a non-ascii-character):

> "Hubert Schölnast" <localpart@domain.tld>

So it seems (to a user of a standard e-mail client like Thunderbird), as if special characters in the quoted section was ok.

But when I check this complete e-mail adress in a perl-script with the cpan-module **Email::Valid** i get an error, saying that this address is not matching the rules of rfc822, and the documentation of this module says, that rfc822 does not allow any non-ascii-character in any part of an e-mail address. (When I omit the letter *ö* or replace it with an ascii-letter, the check says that the address is valid.)

So obviously any e-mail client must encode the e-mail-address before it sends an e-mail to a smtp-server, and must decode it when it received a new e-mail and displays header-information to the user. But I can't find out how this is done, and I really did my best on googling.

I need this encoding-algorithm because I want to write a perl-script that accepts any valid e-mail-address (also with special characters in the quoted section) and then send e-mails to those addresses.

Comment: Incidentally, the double quotes around your real name are not required, and just look like you put it in quotes because it's not your "real" name. (Either that, or you are using email software from Microsoft. Either way, embarrassing.)

Comment: @tripleee: Well, it is my real name (look into my profile). But some e-mail clients (not sure wich one) need quotes when the name contains special characters.

Comment: The value no longer contains any special characters when you RFC2047-encode it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl core has `Encode.pm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

my $from_header = decode_utf8 q{From: "Hubert Schölnast" <localpart@domain.tld>};
print encode('MIME_Header', $from_header);

1;
__END__
From: "=?UTF-8?B?SHViZXJ0IFNjaMO2bG5hc3Q=?=" <localpart@domain.tld>
```

There are a lot of requirements behind RFC822/2822 that makes it hard to deal with emails.

RFC2822 also prohibits every lines in a message to be more than 998 characters.
Long lines must be split across multiple lines by indenting the continuation lines.

This means we have to pay attention to the line length whenever we modify them just **after** of converting of special characters and prepending a header label.

---

## Edit

As of Encode.pm version 2.80, MIME-Header encoding was rewritten to comply RFC2047, the original code that I posted above can not be used nowadays.

See: https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::MIME::Header#BUGS

The most straight-foward alternative is to use both of `Email::MIME` and `Email::Address::XS`, these packages are not in core though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;

use Email::Address::XS;
use Email::MIME::Header::AddressList;

my $address = Email::Address::XS->new('Hubert Schölnast' => 'localpart@domain.tld');
my $addr_list = Email::MIME::Header::AddressList->new($address);

print $addr_list->as_mime_string;

1;
__END__
=?UTF-8?B?SHViZXJ0IFNjaMO2bG5hc3Q=?= <localpart@domain.tld>
```

Comment: Tip: This assumes a UTF-8-encoded source file. In that situation, use `use utf8;`. Then, you don't have to use `decode_utf8` everywhere.

Comment: @ernix: Thank you! I hope, that the cpan-modul Email:Sender correctly deals with line-lenght and all this stuff. This is why I use modules.

Comment: I searched on my mail-server for the files where all my e-mails are stored, and found, that there my address is stored in exactly that way that is produced by `encode('MIME_Header', $address)`. Thank you! (And I always use `use utf8;` in all my scripts, so there is no need for `decode_utf8`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [MIME::Words](http://p3rl.org/MIME::Words) to encode or decode the addresses, subject etc.

E.g. when creating the email:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use MIME::Words qw{ encode_mimeword };

my $encoded = encode_mimeword('Hubert Schölnast');
```

To encode the name with the address, use `encode_mimewords`.

When processing an email, use `decode_mimewords` instead.

Comment: Maybe also link to [RFC2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) which defines this encoding.

Comment: Is it safe to use this method for the complete address (*"Hubert Schölnast" <localpart@domain.tld>*)?

Comment: @tripleee: Thank you for the link, but RFCs are always so long and hard to read. Is there a shorter description of the algorithm?

Comment: In so many words, the encoded  string has the form `=?<charset>?<bq>?<encoded>?=` where *charset* is a character set specifier like `iso-8859-1`, *enc* is  an encoding specifier which is  either `b` for (a variant of) base64 or `q` for (a variant of) quoted-printable, and *encoded* is the thus encoded string.

Comment: Again, you should omit the double quotes, and additiobally, you should not encode the email address -- the encoding is only valid or useful  for the human-readable parts, while the email terminus needs to be unencoded and machine-readable (though with IDNA there is yet another encoding for non-ASCII email addresses, sigh!) A correct implementation should produce  something like `=?utf-8?q?Hubert_Sch=C3=B6lnast?= <localpart@domain.tld>`

Comment: @tripleee: This means, when the user enters something like »**"[Ößé@] <Ñïḉ>" <local@domain.tld>**« into the address field, then I have to extract »**"[Ößé@] <Ñïḉ>"**«, throw away the quotation marks, decode this part and join it again to the part between the angel brackets? Isn't there a simpler way with less pitfalls?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: There is. Its name is MIME::Words.

Comment: @choroba: The string, that MIME::Words produces is - according to Email::Valid - invalid, because it doesn't match the rfc822-restrictions. »**Hubert Schölnast <localpart@domain.tld>**« will be converted to »**=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Hubert=20Sch=F6lnast=20<localpart@domain.tld>?=**«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Use `encode_mimewords` for the full address line.

Comment: @choroba: This is exactly what I did. This is my shortened perl-script (`<|>` is for a line-break): `#!/usr/bin/perl -w <|>
use MIME::Words qw{encode_mimeword}; <|>
print encode_mimeword('Hubert Schölnast <localpart@domain.tld>')."\n";` and this is its output: `=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Hubert=20Sch=C3=B6lnast=20<localpart@domain.tld>?=`

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Plural. `word` ne `words`.